# Flex Multiple Items selection is not working in DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid

I am making a component in mxml file and i am using DataGrid and getting object.
gridTable is the object of the DataGrid and I am trying to select multiple rows by code.
so I am doing

```
gridTable.selectedIndices = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
gridTable.setStyle("horizontalGridLineColor",0xDDAAFF);
```

which is working partially like as below,

this is not showing selected rows at the same time when I do mouse over on the list then it is showing selected rows among all list

if Some buddy has solved this kind of issue please share your Experience.
I am using Flex 4.5.1A and FlashPlayer 10.2.0

Regards
Anuj Jindal

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it will help. You can try with `callLater()` and `validateNow()`.

```
callLater(function():void
{    
     gridTable.selectedIndices = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
     gridTable.setStyle("horizontalGridLineColor",0xDDAAFF);
     gridTable.validateNow();

});
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_12.html